# Inter Thread Communication in C

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

As a part of my project I have to modify a Numerical Integration Algorithm using threads.

This is roughly what happens in the conventional sequential approach..

```
void Controller(struct DE)
{
    //initialization step
    for(;;)   //till the entire range has not been covered...
    {
         //compute the next time-point solution using the previously known solutions.
         NIiter();
         //then check if the result is acceptable or not and take the necessary steps...
    }
}
```

Now this is what I intend to do....

```
void Controller(struct DE)
{
    //initialization step
    for(;;)   //till the entire range has been covered...
    {
         //compute the next time using the previously known solution.
         NIiter();
         //when I have an approximate solution available..launch a thread to compute the next time-point using this approximate solution as a previous solution...something like forward pipelining...
         //then check if BOTH the results are acceptable or not and take the necessary steps...
    }
}
```

But I dont understand how to notify my controller that the an approximate solution is available...so it can launch a new thread...

This is my first exposure to multi-threaded programming...so forgive me if this seems to be an obvious question..also I am using Pthread library in my project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a vast topic but here are some pointers

1. [Worker threads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern) - Basically create a bunch of threads and have a queue of tasks. They take one of the queue and do the job
2. IPC - Here you have semaphores, shared memory, messaging passing. Links are on the [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool_pattern)

The Wikipedia will get you going.

Comment: It would be worth while to quantify "a bunch of threads". If too many are created, it will have a negative impact on the performance. At least one thread per CPU core would be a good starting point.