# What does it mean to send a message to a thread?

Tags: c, multithreading

I am learning about threads. And I need to understand how threads communicate between each other, so what does it mean when we say something like "let `Thread A` send a message to `Thread B`"?

I can think of the following:

- `Thread B` is blocking on some sort of queue, and `Thread A` places a new
  entry in this queue, which causes `Thread B` to unblock, and retrieve
  this entry.
- `Thread B` is blocking on an event (for example, in Windows API there
  is the [Event object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), and `Thread A` signals this event which will
  cause `Thread B` to wake up (or is this called notifying a thread and
  not sending a message to it?)

Comment: Take a look at ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13217809/645128)*** brief conversation.

Comment: The first assertion can be an implementation of the second, and in fact, that's how and win32 event object is roughtly internally implemented

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inter Thread Communication in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13217761/inter-thread-communication-in-c)

Comment: @DourHighArch: ??? I don't see how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "threads" world is subject of many ambiguity due to different nomenclature coming from different environments, sometimes using same words to mean different things.

Your first assertion makes sense in very general terms: the "message" is what makes the thread to wake-up and get some "input".

Depending on the OS and its own API, your second assertion makes sense and is nothing more then a way to implement the first using the Win32 API.

Another possible interpretation can be that the thread is blocked on a message loop (see [GetMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644936(v=vs.85).aspx)) and the other one calls [PostThreadMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946(v=vs.85).aspx).

In a more general term, you can think of a "message" as an "event" that carries a "state" with it: an event simply happens (and that's all the information it gives). A message "happens", and has some parameter associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

Link to example Windows code that uses two threads to copy a file, the original thread reads, a created thread writes. There's a custom messaging system that uses Windows mutexes and semaphores. Other than the overhead to create and delete the mutexes and semaphores, the actual functions are fairly small. I've worked on embedded multi-threaded devices, using a similar messaging interface scheme.

http://rcgldr.net/misc/mtcopy.zip